# Excel VBA How to copy and paste a section of cells into a newly made sheet

Tags: vba, excel, copy, paste

I'm making a budgeter sort of thing that helps people keep track of their money. I currently have a bunch of code that checks the current month and attempts to make a new sheet with the name (MM/YYYY) unless that sheet has already been made, if it has been made then nothing will happen.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    nowMonth = Month(Now)
    nowYear = Year(Now)
    sheetNameStr = nowMonth & "," & nowYear

    sheetExists = False
    For Each Sheet In Worksheets
        If sheetNameStr = Sheet.Name Then
            sheetExists = True
        End If
    Next Sheet
    If sheetExists = False Then
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))
        ws.Name = sheetNameStr
        MsgBox ("New sheet named " & sheetNameStr & "was created")
    End If
    Sheets("Main").Activate

    Worksheets("Main").Range("A5:D300").Copy Worksheets("sheetNameStr").Range("A1")
End Sub
```

The problem I am having is trying to copy and paste the history of my purchases/income and pasting it into the new sheet. I always get the

> Run-time error '9': Subscript out of range

error.

If anyone could help that'd be great thanks!

Comment: Why is this code in the `Worksheet_Change` event? what you are not realy doing anything with `Taregt`, ot anything relatind to a certain change event.

Comment: @ShaiRado Oops - I hadn't even noticed that!  (I guess it could be intentional, i.e. creating a backup copy, by date, every time any sort of change occurs - this each dated sheet gives the status at the end of that day.  But that's potentially a **lot** of copies occurring during the day.)

Comment: My teacher said to put it in there, he said that means everytime something happens it will check if theres a sheet and if there isnt a sheet with the mm/yyyy then it will create one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your line saying

```
Worksheets("Main").Range("A5:D300").Copy Worksheets("sheetNameStr").Range("A1")
```

is referring to a worksheet called `"sheetNameStr"`, but you really want to refer to a sheet with the name contained in the variable `sheetNameStr`, i.e.

```
Worksheets("Main").Range("A5:D300").Copy Worksheets(sheetNameStr).Range("A1")
```

Comment: Thank you! It mostly worked but when the dates carried over they become all #####? Here are some screenshots to show what I am saying

https://gyazo.com/2392e7ec44a91a6af181aa2843cbc4d7
https://gyazo.com/04de88e2fac86b04e78f8d7808ccdf0b

Comment: @Youiee Are you sure you just haven't made the column widths wide enough to fit a date?  (I'm not going to follow those links - if you want me to look at images, edit the question to include them - that way I will know that they are on a safe server.)  Or are the dates based on a formula that is dependent on something that was in (for instance) rows 1 to 4 and is therefore now giving a `#REF` error?

Comment: Oh right sorry you are right again I just had to expand the columns, thank you very much!!